# How to create a CSV file Dynamically using Feed in python?

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I'm exporting data from python with the csv library which works pretty good. After a web-search I can not find any information about how to dynamically place the rows with python.

For example.

```
for table_id in table_ids:
    data_query = gdata.analytics.client.DataFeedQuery({
            'ids': table_id,
            'start-date': datetime.date(2013, 6, 9),
            'end-date': datetime.date(2013, 7, 9),        
            'dimensions': 'ga:Country', 
            'metrics': 'ga:visits, ga:visitors'})
    feed = client.GetDataFeed(data_query)
```

i am exporting as below:

```
for x2 in feed.entry:
    for y2 in x2.dimension:
        csvout.writerow((y2.value.encode('utf-8'),''))
    for z2 in x2.metric:
          csvout.writerow(('',z2.value.encode('utf-8')))
```

it will works for one metric if i want to pass 3 metrics, i need data in different three columns.
anybody an idea how this works?

Comment: Give the writerow method a list in the order of the columns that you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Read it in list and append to writerow method in csvout. then it will work.

Example:

lenDim = range(len(i.dimension))

for lenD in lenDim:

```
             csvList.append(i.dimension[lenD].name)
```

for lenM in lenMet:

```
             csvList.append(i.metric[lenM].name) 

             csvout.writerow(csvList)
```

that's it. it's working fine.